# Longer pageLoadErrorMessage in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I would like to show pageLoadErrorMessage for longer time than it's default. For example 5 seconds. For now this time is too short to be able to read my custom message.

How to achieve that?

Comment: get the un-compressed version of jquery-mobile and modify the code for your needs; looked in the config and there seems to be no way to set this.

Comment: you need to modify this [line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/e4121024ee17856174c617f8c1bca7b322229c52/js/widgets/pagecontainer.js#L429). It's an anonymous/private function which can't be extended/accessed directly.